# PHP file_get_contents giving out of memory issue for more than 20 MB pdf files

Tags: php, mysql, file-get-contents

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('post_max_size','-1');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize','-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time','0');
set_time_limit(0);

$files = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$file_base = base64_encode($files);
```

The above code working fine with files smaller than 20 MB. But when i try to upload pdf file larger than 20MB it is showing out of memory issue like bellow.

`Out of memory (allocated 439840768) (tried to allocate 116729376 bytes)`

I need to store the pdf file in blob format in MySQL database without saving it in folder or some location.

I have changed all the settings in php.ini file to increase the memory limit, upload max size and execution time but no use.

I have checked all the solutions in stackoverflow and some other domains but not found useful answer.

Comment: After you have changed the php.ini , make sure you restart the httpd service

Comment: are you sure that the code you shared is the whole code that has the error? Your error shows that PHP managed to allocate about 0.5gb memory already that should have been more than enough for an e.g. 50mb file. Is there anything else going on that's depleting the memory before you even reach this point?

Comment: @KenLee I have restarted the Xampp server.

Comment: @apokryfos I did the debug in every step by commenting line by line. Only at the line which i used file_get_contents giving this error. When i try to upload pdf file which has 15MB, it is working fine.

Comment: Question: **[As a test]** if you remove the line `$file_base = base64_encode($files);` (and do not save the data into db), what happens ? Do you still have out of memory errors ?

Comment: Why are you converting to Base64? A blob stores binary content.